# Can someone explain what these special variables mean?

Tags: solaris, sh

I'm re-learning scripting and found an example the book doesn't explain very well.

e.g.:

```
if [ ! $# -eq 0 ]
```

This is testing to determine if '$#' does not equal zero, yes?

But what then is the value of '$#'?

Are there others?

```
'#@', '#?' ?
```

Thank you

Comment: you mean `$@` and `$?`, right? `$@` is all argument values passed into the script available as 1 variable, and `$?` is the return code of the previously executed cmd. To see that at its bare bones, do `true; echo $?; false ; echo $?`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$#` is the number of the arguments you passed to your script.

For example, your have script called `a.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $#
```

And you run it like

```
/bin/bash a.sh 1 2 3
```

you will get `3`.

There are others like `$@`.